# rsyslog UDP port changing

Tags: rsyslog, udp

I'm trying to setup log forwarding with rsyslog. I have the line below in my rsyslog.conf file just to test sending logs over.

```
*.* @<remoteserverIP>:514
```

I'm trying to send the logs over UDP port 514. However, when I do a netstat, it appears the logs are going over a random port like 6023. The port is different every time I restart the rsyslog daemon. I've checked the firewall and IP tables rules, but I can't find anything setup that would be changing the outbound port. I have another server sending to the same remote syslog server that is working just fine. I'd appreciate any ideas of what I might check to get this working.

Comment: The local port changes, the remote port should not.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected for a client to change, that is, to be an [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). It is the remote server which should not. There a few services for which this is not the case, most notably `ntp`, but such is not the case for syslog.